# python convert webdriver object into webdriver-wire object is it possible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

We have many authentication frontend operations what we really like to have full monitoring on the request/response headers and request bodies when testing browsers.
This works with selenium-wire, but it is so slow because of all the communication.

Is it possible to convert an existing selenium-webdriver Webelement into a selenium-webdriver-wire object without having to start with `driver.get(url)`?

Example below use 2.5sec on webdriver, but 13.6sec in webdriver-wire and this is one single call, we have 3-4 stages before we have the complete url+headers+bodies+tokens we like to wire.

I would save minutes if I can shortcut it and logging. Also tips on how to speed it up are greatly appreciated.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumwire import webdriver as wdwire
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

t0 = time.time()
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_III"
wd.get(url)
el = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='infobox vcard']")))
print(el)
print(el.text[:10] + f"..<total len:{len(el.text)}>")
print(f"webdriver used:{time.time()-t0:.2f}sec")


t0 = time.time()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--log-level=3') #wire logs a lot!!!!
wd = wdwire.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get(url)
el = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='infobox vcard']")))
print(el)
print(el.text[:10] + f"..<total len:{len(el.text)}>")
print(f"webdriver-wire used:{time.time()-t0:.2f}sec")
```

cat .\requirements.txt

```
selenium>=4.9.0
selenium-wire>=5.1.0
```

Output:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53645/devtools/browser/8e5340a8-f62f-4823-bf68-211c53735d46
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a10ba6e3dfe51c79b981492e5a99eeb0", element="6E59F578DADEE86AFCA448EB2886D53E_element_48")>
Charles II..<total len:849>
webdriver used:2.57sec

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53683/devtools/browser/7bf4ed09-27e5-4578-b6a6-50d9c2c8824b
[25360:23692:0508/105242.606:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [10:52:42.605] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: Systemet finner ikke angitt fil. (0x2)
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="252f14b720ea379966ac0c0fe769c5a9", element="2F5C250D2C0574BB7FD21321CC6556CC_element_45")>
Charles II..<total len:849>
webdriver-wire used:13.61sec
```